# WScript.GetObject() does not work, but GetObject() does

Tags: vbscript, wsh

When using VBScript to get processes list on Windows 7 Pro, this script, named as **getobject.vbs**, is used:

```
Dim objWMIService

'
' case 1: this works:
'
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
WScript.Echo "GetObject() worked."

'
' case 2: this does not work:
'
Set objWMIService = WScript.GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
WScript.Echo "WScript.GetObject() does not work. So this line never runs."

'
' ...
'
Set objWMIService = Nothing
```

In case 1, GetObject() works well.

But in case 2, when WScript.GetObject() is used, this error occurs:

[image]

GetObject() is a method of WScript, please see [Microsoft ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ywk619w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)..
Why cannot one call it by the complete reference in the form of **WScript.GetObject()**?

As a comparision, the both calls worked:

```
Dim xobj

Set xobj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set xobj = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Answer (score 4):

There is [a GetObject function of the VBScript language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdccchxa%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) **and** [a GetObject method of the WScript object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ywk619w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). They are not the same, their prototypes and usage/pragmatics differ.

**Update wrt comment:**

Read Eric Lippert's [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/06/01/145686.aspx) to understand why there are host- **and** language-provided variants of similar functions.

My rule of thump: Use the language version of Create/GetObject(), except when you **need** the extras (e.g. events) provided by the host application.

Comment: Do you mean that I'm using VBScript::GetObject() when calling bare GetObject() method. I failed in calling WScript.GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2"), or WScript.GetObject("", "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2"). What's the way to  use WScript.GetObject() method? or there is none?